Page preview displays form with table A fields but no sub-grid of related table in Power pages
So, I have a form made in table A with a sub-grid pointing to its related table B. Both tables have a row inside. The form with the default table A info fields shows up fine but the sub-grid is missing from the preview page. I want to also mention in the form designer the sub-grid displays and shows not records even if there is a row inside the related table. Check the steps below to re-create my solution and maybe there is an issue to be found in the steps that I do not see. If it helps I have also added a List component pointing to the related table and the list shows up the items fine. The idea also is to create new elements in the sub-grid with a quick create form. Additional info is that I am a newbie and still learning the environment.
**Steps to follow:**

Parent table: Order

Child table: Order item

Relationship between tables: Order --- one to many ---> Order item

**Step 1 - Create Tables:**
**Order table** fields:
Name (Primary column, text)
Order date (Date only)

Create row within the table.

**Order item** fields:
      - Item name (primary column, text)
      - Order (Lookup to the Order item table)
      - Quantity (whole number)
      - Price (whole number)

Create row within the table.

The rows will serve as the master row (heard it's necessary for the sub-grid to display data).
Probably will change it into a multi-step form later into development if this is the case.

**Step 2 - Quick create form for Order item table**
      2.1 Go to make.powerapps.com
      2.2 Select the Tables section from the left
      2.3 Select the Order item table
      2.4 Select Properties (on the Table properties section)
      2.5 From the Properties tab, select Advanced options
      2.6 Scroll all the way down and in the For this table section select Leverage quick-create form if available and hit the Save button
      2.7 Now still on the table page, in the top left of the page select New -> Hover over Form -> Quick create form
      2.8 Create a new quick create form with the Item name, order, quantity and price. Save the form.

**Step 3 - Make the view for the sub-grid**
      3.1 From the power pages designer go to the Data section.
      3.2 Select the Order item table
      3.3 Select Views
      3.4  Make a new view, with the columns of order item (Item name, quantity and price). Save the view.

**Step 4 - Make the form for the info of Order table + the sub-grid for Order item table**
      4.1 Again select Data from the Power Pages designer
      4.2 Select the Order table.
      4.3 Go to Forms
      4.4 Use the default form or create a new one
      4.5  Add the Order table column fields first (Order name and Order date)
      4.6 Click on Add component -> Sub-grid -> Show related records -> Order item table -> View, the view you just created in step 3
      4.7 Save the form 

**Step 5** - Add permissions for Order and Order item table **
      For testing sake I have basically enabled all CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operation permissions with global access and to all web roles 
      (anonymous, administrator, authenticated users (the default roles)).

      5.1 Go to the Power Pages Management (three dots from the power pages designer - > Power Pages Management)
      5.2 On the left, scroll down until you get to Table permissions section, click it
      5.3 On the Table permissions page  click on Create (Add or whatever it says I have the portal in Dutch) and make a new permission.
      5.4 You have to create two permissions with global access, full CRUD operations all selected and enable the all 3 default roles ((anonymous, administrator, authenticated         users). Save both permissions. 

**Step 6 - Add the form to the page and preview it**


The issue was that the Order table was an insert form. Sub-grid's won't display when a form is in insert mode due to the fact that you can not create something for which it does not exist yet.Therefore if an order does not exist to what order item to relate it to ?
The solution was to just make a new basic form which is in Edit action then it's gonna work.
